# I have the following phasor −j3e^(−jβx). How can I find just the real part

Tags: electricity

−j3e^(−jβx) for this phasor I am trying to figure out what to do with the -j3 thats is being multiplied by the expodentional. I am not sure how I can find the real part with this being there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Expand the exponential from [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) and multiply it by -3j. Then it'll be straightforward to find out the real part.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the variables are real, we have:

$$-\text{j}\exp\left(-x\beta\text{j}\right)=-\text{j}\cdot\left(\cos\left(-x\beta\right)+\sin\left(-x\beta\right)\cdot\text{j}\right)=$$
$$-\text{j}\cdot\cos\left(-x\beta\right)-\text{j}\cdot\sin\left(-x\beta\right)\cdot\text{j}=$$
$$\sin\left(-x\beta\right)-\cos\left(-x\beta\right)\cdot\text{j}=$$
$$-\sin\left(x\beta\right)-\cos\left(x\beta\right)\cdot\text{j}\tag1$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can use [Euler's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) as a first step:

\$e^{jx}=\cos{x} + j\sin{x}\$